# Oracle Jet - How to route to another module from inside a module

Tags: oracle-jet

Using part of the default Yeoman Default Oracle Dashboard generated to illustrate my problem:

```
../src/index.html
../src/js/appController.js
../src/js/main.js
../src/js/views/dashboard.html 
../src/js/views/customers.html
../src/js/viewModels/dashboard.js
../src/js/viewModels/customers.js
```

If I'm in the dashboard module and I want to to something like

```
 function DashboardViewModel() {
...
self.currentRowListener = function (event, ui) {
Router.rootInstance.go('customers');
}
...
```

How can I do that? I can't find a way to redirect to another module from whitin a specific module

Answer (score 1):

The `Router.go` function is the right way to do it, you just have to obtain it using `oj.Router.rootInstance`. Provided you configured your router correctly - which I suppose is the case as you use a default template - this should be all.

Example:

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'ojs/ojrouter'], function (oj) {
    function DashboardViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.currentRowListener = function (event, ui) {
            oj.Router.rootInstance.go('customers');
        }
    }
    return DashboardViewModel;
});
```

Comment: Very nice it works perfectly.. I just forgot to add the ojs/router in the define declaration